# Dynamically Assign Variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dynamic-variables

I have the following function as part of a large codebase, which I inherited:

```
function = save_function(fpath, a,b,c)
    save(fpath, 'a', 'b', 'c')
end
```

This function is called at the end of one script, before another script is to be executed. This way, the variable names are properly saved (bad design, I know - I didn't write this code).

Now, I am making changes to the codebase, and realize that I need to store more variables in `fpath`. I face two options:

1. Edit `save_function` to accept more inputs. This would break any other code in the codebase that also uses this function
2. Write a `save_function2(a, b, c, d, e, ...)` that I will call in the code that I change. This seems like bad design as well.

What I would ideally like to do, is to allow `save_function` to take in any number of arguments at a time, and save them all by the variable names that are passed in.

Having done some googling, I found `eval` and `eval_in`, which evaluate strings as matlab code. However, there are two problems with using this:

1. Using `eval` is horribly slow and quite dangerous
2. I don't always know the types of my variables beforehand, so I can't create an elegant, generic `to_string` function

In order to combat the flexible number of variables, I decided to use `varargin` and `inputname` as follows:

```
function = save_function(fpath, varargin)
    names = {}
    for i=1:size(varargin,1)
        names{i} = inputname(i+1);  % have to offset by 1 to account for fpath
    end
    save(fpath, names{:});
end
```

Unfortunately, since the input variables are held in `varargin`, they do not exist as their variable names on the stack, so the `save` line fails

How can I dynamically create these variables on the stack, with their variable names?

Comment: I’m 6 years late, but it seems that you want to call `save` directly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a structure to dynamically define saved variable names.
This option is documented [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/save-structure-fields-as-separate-variables.html).

```
 function save_function( fpath, varargin )     
 for ii = 1:numel( varargin )
     st.( inputname(ii+1) ) = varargin{ii};
 end
 save( fpath, '-struct', 'st' );
```

As a rule of thumb, [structure with dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) is often better than `eval` or `assignin` when it comes to dynamic variable names.

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: Changing `save_function` to save a struct is undesirable, since other parts of the large codebase expect it to save the variables themselves.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget read carefully the manual regarding the `'-struct'` flag in save: it does not save the struct, but save the struct fields as seperate variables, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `assignin`, which takes a workspace, a variable name, and some data. It then creates, in the specified workspace, a variable with the given name, whose value is the data:

```
assignin(workspace, varname, value)
```

The workspace identifier can be either `'caller'` or `'base'`. The former creates the variable in the workspace of the function that called the function within which `assignin` is called; while the latter... I don't know - it doesn't seem to put the variable anywhere I can see.

The trick is to create a small function to assign variables to the calling workspace, and call this function from within `assignin`:

```
function = save_function(fpath, varargin)
    names = {}
    for i=1:size(varargin,1)
        names{i} = inputname(i+1);  % have to offset by 1 to account for fpath
    end
    create_variables(names, varargin);
    save(fpath, names{:});
end

function = create_variables(names, vals)
    for i=1:size(names, 1)
        assignin('caller', names{i}, vals{i});
    end
end
```